# Russian dictionary with IPA transcription

Tags: обучение

Is there a good bilingual Russian dictionary with IPA transcription only for the Russian section?
Any of the following options is okay: English-Russian-English or, instead of English, Italian, French, Spanish or Portuguese.
Thank you very much indeed for your help.
Abele Cansella

Comment: there is dictionary russian french with IPA( russian )name of dictionary is :assimil

Answer (score 7):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA#Pronunciation) has IPA for most Russian words.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer, but what I need is a printed dictionary.

Comment: @Abele - There's one more online dictionary with IPA transcription of Russian words, Russian-German:
http://www.uni-leipzig.de/russisch/online-woerterbuch/

Comment: @Abele - One more, [Russian Phonetic Transcription Converter](http://learn-foreign-language-phonetics.com/russian-phonetic-transcription-converter.php?site_language=english), converts Russian text into IPA transcription.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a dictionary of words' stresses of Russian. It could be helpful at studying Russian, consider the stresses are less straightforward than transcription:

[Зарва М.В. Русское словесное ударение: Словарь. - Около 50 000 слов. - М.: Изд-во НЦ ЭНАС, 2001. - 600 с.](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

Comment: Your answer is very useful, but what I need is a bilingual dictionary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to a dictionary with transcription that I've found online is [rhymes](http://rifmovnik.ru/find), which gives full declensions for nouns and adjectives, as well as full conjugations of verbs, and can optionally display pronunciation. However, the transcription is not IPA, but rather a cyrillic based system which you can easily learn.

When you enter a word, you have to choose **словоформа** from the drop-down menu and then check **транскрипция** on the definition page for the transcription.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

IPA is not suitable for the Russian language. Most Russian dictionaries do not have transcription, because the pronunciation can be easily derived from the spelling.

Comment: Most is not all. The case of silent letters is a rather difficult one for many non-russian speakers to understand. (i.e. «здравствуйте»)

Comment: @Volodya - «Здравствуйте» is very often pronounced as [drasʲ] :D

Comment: Volodya's words encourage me to persist in looking for a printed dictionary. Thank you!

Comment: I don't agree with this statement at all. Russian has enough exceptions and variation between stressed and unstressed vowels that it is perfectly suited for transcription. The problem is that the IPA is a nightmare with Russian, especially because of the superscript [j] used to mark the soft consonants. It looks like an apostrophe and if there are several soft consonants together, it's dizzying. The symbol for softness used to be a subscript tail: s̡   but that was replaced by that infernal superscript.

Comment: @CocoPop I never saw that hook below a letter as a symbol of softness in a Russian transcription, when it was used?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: The superscript j replaced the left hook in 1989. Here's an article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolete_and_nonstandard_symbols_in_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: And here's an entire book on Russian phonetics using the left hook throughout: http://books.google.com/books?id=A9rrVMQ-PxsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+phonetics+of+russian&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zMERVJaqH8-mggT8jYHQDg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=s&f=false.  By the way, this is one of the best books on the subject for English students of Russian. Note how elegant the transcriptions were with the left hook.

Comment: @CocoPop Russian has its own transcription system, which is taught in school as "phonetic analysis". Usually Russian dictionaries include transcriptions in this system for words that are read not following the usual rules.

Comment: @Anixx: I understand that. English also has its own transcription system used in dictionaries and the like. But the IPA is an International Phonetic Alphabet used to describe the phonologies of all world language, regardless of their own system(s).

Comment: @CocoPop it is unsuitable for Russian, for instance it has no symbol for how я is read. Also it reflects the same Russian phonemes with different symbols. I think it is English-centric. Also I have encountered that what IPA symbols are used for the same sound depends on for what language IPA is used (some proponents claim there is no single IPA but narrow and wide IPA etc, but it is not convincing).

Comment: There is more than one phonetic representation of я: in stressed syllables, it's IPA [ja], in pretonic syllables such as in язы́к it's [jɪ], etc. It's not that mysterious a letter. Aside from the symbols, there are also other diacritics that lower and raise vowels to exact positions in the speaking apparatus.

Comment: I agree that there is some inconsistencies in the use of the symbols in different languages, but that's just usually for the sake of practicality. For example, if two languages have a long [ɑː] sound, but in one it’s a little more backed, both sounds would probably use just [ɑː] since it would be pedantic and unreasonable to always represent the backing [ɑ̝ː] in transcriptions (unless the situation calls for a very narrow transcription).

Comment: These details are usually laid out in the phonology of the language, so that the reader is familiar with the sounds each symbol represents without having to always display suprasegmentals and diacritics ad nauseam.

Comment: @CocoPop "in stressed syllables, it's IPA [ja]". No. It is different from IPA [a] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_unrounded_vowel IPA simply has no symbol for this vowel, even though it can be encountered in many languages besides Russian, and reflected in their alphabet. In Estonian/Finnish alphabet it is denoted as ä. IPA uses [æ] for E/F equivalent of я (again the same sound denoted differently), but the pronounciations recorded for both [a] and [æ] in IPA in Wikipedia have nothing to do with these vowels. The Wikipedia's recording for [a] corresponds to Russian "a", not "я"

Comment: In other words, it's fronted and slightly lowered: it would be [⊢a̞]. Not all sounds have their own symbols. In most cases, the closest cardinal vowel is the symbol, and any fine-tuning is done with suprasegmentals and diacritics. So for instance, although пять is traditionally represented as [pʲætʲ], I agree this is too extreme. It should be [pʲ⊢a̞tʲ]. However, in this case, I would go to the nearest cardinal vowel, /æ/, and define it as representing [⊢a̞] in the case of Russian.

Comment: And if I had my way, it would be [p̡⊢a̞t̡]

Comment: @CocoPop  it is not fine-tuning, it is basic thing. I recognize only 10 vowels. 5 core ones (a, o, u, i, e) and 5 their variations. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/7322/624 I do not know how IPA has more simbols for vowels (for what they use them?) but do not have symbols for these 10 basic ones, which are reflected in many alphabets and phonemically significant.

Comment: @CocoPop also, я in пять and in пьянь is the same, in the letter case it is iotized (has [j] consonant preceding), but the vowels are the same. Yet IPA uses [a] for one word and [æ] for the other (and neither as recorded in Wikipedia is similar to Russian я)

Comment: I have voted this answer up from -1 because I fully agree with its basic thrust: beginners asking for Russian dictionaries with phonetic transcriptions are misguided, likely misinformed by exposure to the highly idiosyncratic spelling of English. They should be told to forget about transcription until they have learned the alphabet and phonetics. Tell them how to pronounce "что" and "-ого", explain about devoicing, consonant clusters, and accented and unaccented vowels. Then they need to practice and practice. They don't need IPA to describe deviations from rules they haven't learned yet.

Comment: @David42 yes, and besides, IPA is influenced by English spelling a lot. For instance, the "diphtong" [aɪ] is phonetically just a vowel plus a consonant [j]. Similarly, the sound of Russian letter ц is represented in IPA with 3 Unicode characters [t͡s] while it can be encountered in multiple languages and in them it is denoted usually by one letter (Russian, German, Hebrew, Japanese are some examples). Many different IPA symbols for vowels mean actually the same phoneme in Russian, etc. Russian has its own transcription system, called "phonetic analysis" and learned in school.